# Unix - sed get value from a line after a first colon

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a file (newline.txt) that contains the following line

```
Footer - Count: 00034300, Facility: TRACE, File Created: 20160506155539
```

I am trying to get the value after `Count:` up to the comma (in the example `00034300`) from this line.

I tried this but I get is all the numbers concatenated into one large string with that command:

```
grep -i "Count:" newfile.txt | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

output:0003430020160506155539

how do I get just the digits after `Count:` up to to the first non-digit character?

I just need 00034300.

Comment: You **never** need to pipe the output of `grep` to `sed`, since `sed` can do anything `grep` can.

Answer (score 7):

#### Using sed

```
$ sed '/[Cc]ount/ s/[^:]*: *//; s/,.*//' newline.txt 
00034300
```

How it works:

- `/[Cc]ount/` selects lines containing `Count` or `count`.  This eliminates the need for `grep`.
- `s/[^:]*: *//` removes everything up to the first colon including any spaces after the colon.
- In what remains, `s/,.*//` removes everything after the first comma.

#### Using awk

```
$ awk -F'[[:blank:],]' '/[Cc]ount/ {print $4}' newline.txt 
00034300
```

How it works:

- `-F'[[:blank:],]'` tells awk to treat spaces, tabs, and commas as field separators.
- `/[Cc]ount/` selects lines that contain `Count` or `count`.
- `print $4` prints the fourth field on the selected lines.

#### Using grep

```
$ grep -oiP '(?<=Count: )[[:digit:]]+' newline.txt 
00034300
```

This looks for any numbers following `Count:` and prints them.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. that worked. :)